# Optimum chunk size for playing video

Tags: node.js, video, optimization, server

I am implementing server-side of an application which will serve video to clients. The way my video streaming works is that the browser asks for a part of the video file in an open ended format, eg. it says - send video.mp4 from byte# 30456 onwards (lets assume every video is 100*1024*1024 bytes (100 MB)).  The browser makes multiple such requests to the server.

Question: How can I calculate the optimum size of video data I should serve on every such request?

Lets say my server will run on a 100Mbps network and I need to concurrently serve 50k clients.